# Why does float() cut off trailing zeros?

Tags: python, math, floating-point, numbers, decimal

The code successfully crops a large file of many numbers to several smaller text files with number, but it produces an interesting quirk.

All numbers should be to four decimal points like 2.7400 but instead they print as 2.74.

Here is a snippet from a file

```
0.96
0.53
0.70
0.53
0.88
0.97
```

Why does this happen? Is there a way to fix this or this just a quirk of float()?

```
from itertools import islice

def number_difference(iterable):
    return float(iterable[-1].strip('\n')) - float(iterable[0].strip('\n'))

def file_crop(big_fname, chunk_fname, no_lines):
    with open(big_fname, 'r') as big_file:
        big_file.readline()
        ifile = 0
        while True:
            data = list(islice(big_file, no_lines))
            if not data:
                break
            with open('{}_{}.locs'.format(chunk_fname, ifile), 'w') as small_file:
                offset = int(float(data[0].strip('\n')))
    map(lambda x: str(float(x.strip('\n')) - offset) + '\n', data)
    small_file.write('{} {} L\n'.format(len(data), number_difference(data)))
        small_file.write(''.join(map(lambda x: str(round((float(x.strip('\n')) - offset),4)) + '\n', data)))
            ifile += 1
```

Comment: The `float` representations for 2.74 and 2.7400 are identical.  There is no way to know how many extra irrelevant zeros were used in the original string representation after it has been converted to `float`.

Comment: A `float` represents a number, and trailing zeros aren't a property of the number. 2.74 = 2.7400.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IEEE 754 floating point numbers (of which `float` is [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)) are not designed to hold precision information. If you need to do so then you should use `decimal.Decimal` instead.

```
>>> decimal.Decimal('0.70')
Decimal('0.70')
>>> print decimal.Decimal('0.70')
0.70
```

See the [`decimal` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) for full details.

Comment: Thanks! I wil look into 'decimal.Decimal'

Answer (score 6):

You can keep the zeros by formatting the output:

eg: if the output is 0.96,

```
x= 0.96
"{0:.4f}".format(x)
```

Output:

```
'0.9600'
```

The output will be a string though..

The below article might be a good read:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

It explains why Python displays floats in the above format.

Comment: This doesn't answer the "why" part of the question

Comment: This should be the real answer. The original question was about printing the results.

Answer (score 0):

A floating point number is simply an approximation in python (and other programming language)...for example  a  decimal is computed as a binary value. It is difficult to find the exact values for most base 10 operations

After carefully reviewing this link, you will see why python does not gave exact values for your operations converted in base 2

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

using print can also do the job

```
print("%.4f" % 0.96) or
whatever_file.write("%.4f" % 0.96)
```